# How can I validate material UI datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, datepicker

I have MUI datepicker. I want to validate it. As we know that days of month can be maximum 31 and months can be maximum 12. I want to prevent user from entering more than 31 days and 12 months. Right now user can add an infinite number of days and months. How can I do so? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-https-wfz9mf

Comment: I don't understand this question. If you don't put a valid date, the component will display a red outline indicating it's not a valid input. Do you mean validating it after the user would press submit?

Comment: I don't want to allow user to write invalid date, like if user wants to write any value that is greater than 12 for months, it shouldn't allow user to write. Same is case for day, I don't want to allow user to write more than 31 in days field. How can I add this validation? This is what I meant. @antipopp